# Using $.post to send JS variables to PHP script

Tags: php, javascript, .post

I am trying to send Javascript variables over to a PHP script for updating scores of a quiz game. I've looked up the shorthand method of doing this, which is $.post, but I am unable to retrieve the values in the PHP script. I am fairly unfamiliar which JS and require help as to what I am doing wrong.

Here is the Javascript

```
function updatescore(){
            var thisgamemarks= 2300;
            var thequizid = 5;
            $.post("updatemark.php", { quizidvalue: thequizid, newmarkvalue: thisgamemarks } );
            }
```

And the PHP

```
$studentnewmark = $POST['newmarkvalue'];
$thisquizid = $POST['quizidvalue'];
$thisstudentid = $_SESSION['studentid'];
```

Comment: what errors do you get, if any, in the javascript console?

Comment: Off the top of my head: maybe $.post doesn't send stuff as request parameters, but serialised as JSON in the request body. Maybe there's a way to dump the whole request in PHP?

Comment: try print_r ( $_POST ) on php side, debug it in browser console

Comment: So far found no errors on the console

Answer (score 8, accepted):

type $_POST instead of $POST. also, on a windows based machine, you can use ctrl + shift + j to debug a js script - which will help if if there's any problems with your code. but, the js code you have shown us looks perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. As suggest use the $_POST instead of $POST and try putting the "quizidvalue" in the javascript inside quotations. It might help. Just a thought. It's how I always do it.